# Jesus marks on Apostle Paul's body

Tags: galatians

I don't understand quite well Galatians 6.17
What are Jesus marks on Paul's body. Does he want to talk about his strips after being beaten up for the gospel or spiritual marks. Do we believers also bear the same marks and what are they exactly?

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, here's what Logos says:

> Galatians 6:17 (LEB): **17** Finally, let no one cause me trouble, for I carry on my body the marks of Jesus.
>
> > **the marks of Jesus** Paul refers to the persecution he endured for preaching the gospel message (e.g., Acts 14:19; 21:30–32). Paul interprets his suffering on behalf of the gospel in terms of Jesus’ crucifixion, because he shares in it (Gal 2:19–20; 6:14).

So, it seems you're suspicion is correct: "the marks of Jesus" probably refer to Paul's scars he got from persecution and punishments.

He may also be undermining circumcision. In Gal 6:11-17, Paul urges the Galatians to not get circumcised. "I carry on my body" may be his way of surpassing circumcision, since it's only "marks" on the genitals.

About your next question:

> "Do we believers also bear the same marks[?]"

For now, I'll say that in Gal 6:17 specifically, Paul is not addressing all Christians, only his own persecution. He's saying that he is a true apostle and witness and his scars and injuries are proof of that because he got them from persecution.

You're question is still interesting, and you might be more satisfied by asking on [Christianity Stack Exchange](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/), because my attempt to answer will probably discuss Christian doctrine, which BH isn't for. If I'm wrong then I'll gladly edit this post to give you a more complete answer.